# How to fix Git Segmentation fault error on Centos

Tags: git, segmentation-fault, centos7

I am getting Segmentation fault error, and could not pull the code on server (Centos 7)

This is how i got to the error, by using below command to verify if my server authenticate with the bitbucket:-

`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

When i use git pull command, i get the following error:-

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

What i have already done to solve this issue:-

1. My SSH key is perfectly added to bitbucket account and same does exist on the server.
2. SSH Username is correct, and repo has the same user permission.
3. I checked to see if it authenticate with bitbucket, and got to know that its a Segmentation fault error.
4. I reinstalled the git on centos 7 server to solve the issue, but no change, it still has the same error. I used following command to reinstall git:-

   `sudo yum reinstall git`

Please help