# Cloning private repository with cPanel SSH key throw error "permission denied"

Tags: ssh, terminal, gitlab, cpanel

1. I accessed my cPanel server via SSH with help of username@host and password.
2. Generated SSH key (RSA) and added it to my GitLab account.
3. When I tried cloning it shows me an error, `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

I think this is an error from the cPanel side but not able to resolve, help me out

Answer (score 1):

From your CPanel server session, check if your generated key works with:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

If you don't see a `Welcome to GitLab, @username!` at the end, that means the key is not properly registered.

Comment: I tried this too, but that is saying ```segmentation fault```

Comment: @ShivamShukla What version Of Git, and OS are you using? What kind of shell/CMD are you in?

Comment: on hosting side i have centOS, while git version is 2.29, although there not issue with git, as i jave found this is happening with SSH, while running command ```ssh -T git@gitlab.com``` it is saying segmentation fault

Comment: @ShivamShukla Maybe an update would help, as in https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-services-failing-segfaults.112377/? `upcp --force`

Comment: my cPanel is on the latest build, 90... which is the latest build stable release

Comment: i got the same question exaclty relevant to my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/61631423/11451771

Comment: @ShivamShukla Strange. That really needs to be reported to their support team.